# Qt storing and accessing big data array

Tags: c++, qt, data-storage

In my Qt app I receive large data array from the remote server (in JSON) then parse it and storing it in `QVariantList`. Every element has certain fields (4 int and 3 string attributes). 
The question is about performance. Should I use an array of `struct` instead of `QVariantList`? Or something else? 
Will it speed up the search by attribute in array and reduce memory usage or there is no difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, replacing QVariantList to struct most likely will speed up your app in this case. To check if an element has specific attribute, you need to extract a string from QVariantList and compare it with the search request. If there are many objects, it will take much time. If an attribute is already stored in QString, comparation will be much faster.

However, it's hard to say for certain what will be faster. Only profilter can tell you that.

Comment: Do you mean that qVariant.toString() is too expensive operation?

Comment: Not only `QVariant::toString`, but also `QVariantList::at`. They are not very expensive, but they are surely more expensive that not doing them.

Comment: So I should not also use QList<myStruct> here? As the QList::at is the same operation

Comment: If you were thinking about using QVariantList or MyStruct for storing one element, so you need `QList<QVariantList>` or `QList<MyStruct>` for storing many of them, don't you? Or were you thinking about storing all objects in one QVariantList? What would be its elements in this case?

Comment: At this moment I have `QVariantList` (not `QList<QVariantList>`), and I was thinking about `QList<MyStruct>`. Or completely reject QList...

Comment: What are the items of QVariantList? You said that "every element has certain fields". In which form is each element stored in your QVariantList?

Comment: Every item is QVariantMap with properties (such as id, name, size)

Comment: Well, it's like `QList<QVariantMap>` (but not exactly). Anyway, `QList` is very convenient for storing a list of objects, and there is no much faster alternative. So you'd better keep `QList<MyStruct>`.